# Making RSSEntry Reader iPhone App

Tags: ios

I try to make an iOS apps that have to download data off of the Internet, but I run into a lot of challenges. You have to:

I list some of these challenges below.

- Write code to retrieve the data off of the network
- Write code to parse and interpret the data
- Write code to run the above in the background, so MY app remains responsive

That’s a lot of different concepts to put together.

The first thing I try to do is create a class to keep track of individual articles inside a RSS feed. ESSENTIALLY, I want to Select the Classes group, go to File\New File, choose iOS\Cocoa Touch Class\Objective-C class, Name the class RSSEntry.m, make sure “Also create RSSEntry.h” is checked, and click Finish.

Here's the code that I have for my property RSSEntry.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface RSSEntry : NSObject {
NSString *_blogTitle;
NSString *_articleTitle;
NSString *_articleUrl;
NSDate *_articleDate;
}

@property (copy) NSString *blogTitle;
@property (copy) NSString *articleTitle;
@property (copy) NSString *articleUrl;
@property (copy) NSDate *articleDate;

- (id)initWithBlogTitle:(NSString*)blogTitle articleTitle:(NSString*)articleTitle articleUrl:(NSString*)articleUrl articleDate:(NSDate*)articleDate;

@end
```

I just try to create a simple class that just stores information about each article. e.g. its title, url, and date, as well as the name of the blog it came from.

Can someone please help me to see what I need to do next step to make my RSSEntry.m ???
I know that I need synthesizes the properties and creates an initializer for the program to work.

```
#import "RSSEntry.h"
@implementation RSSEntry
@synthesize blogTitle = _blogTitle;
@synthesize articleTitle = _articleTitle;
@synthesize articleUrl = _articleUrl;
@synthesize articleDate = _articleDate;
```

Update: The question is already being answer.

Comment: Did you consider using Core Data to store the data? Because the approach would be different.

Comment: You do not need to use @synthesize any more, and haven't for some time. If you're using a book, it is probably out of date. Get a newer one! Things change VERY fast in iOS. The Apple documentation is usually up to date. If you're just starting, try this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011343

Comment: yes. I see your point. this will need new update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is outdated. You do not need to use @synthesize any more, and haven't for some time.  The [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011343) is usually up to date.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to look up the most update VERSION of this.  I found the most updated tutorial to ios developing. Here's the iOS 7 version. 
Get a newer one! Things change VERY fast in iOS. The Apple documentation is usually up to date. I try this tutorial below:

Comment: This seems unfinished.